# How do you get a Profile Picture for a Sharepoint SocialComment.Owner

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am using the SocialCommentManager.GetComments method to get an array of social comments, I need to get the profile picture of the comment.Owner but can't find how to do it.

Some sample code of how I am retrieving the comments:

```
        SocialComment[] comments = mySocialCommentManager.GetComments(CurrentPage.Uri); //ToDo: Update parameters to allow paging

        foreach (SocialComment comment in comments)
        {
             //ToDo: Get comment.Owner profile pricture somehow
```

Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

comment.Owner contains value of type "UserProfile". UserProfile's picture is stored in field "PictureURL". So your code will be something like this:

```
foreach (SocialComment comment in comments)
{
   UserProfile up = comment.Owner;
   if (up["PictureURL"] != null && up["PictureURL"].Value != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(up["PictureURL"].Value.ToString()))
   {
     string pictureUrl = up["PictureURL"].Value.ToString();
   } else {
     //picture is not defined
   }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Thanks,

Dmitry - pdfsharepoint.com